# RegEx for starting with certain character sets, a space, and then certain years

Tags: regex

Needing help for a RegEx (using Oracle REGEXP_LIKE) to identify strings that:

1. Start with any of the following:

- P
- C
- (P)
- (C)
- ©

2. are then followed by a space
3. are then followed by any 4-digit numbers, where the first 2 digits in the number are 19 or 20.
4. are then followed by a space
5. are then followed by any other text

Sample matches:

- (P) 2004 XYZ Company
- P 2018 This is some random text
- (C) 1994 More Random Text

Sample non-matches:

- (P) XYZ Company
- P1976,Just Wow
- (C) 1856 Too Late For Gold

I've started with

```
^[PC©]\s+
```

but, as a beginner, am stumped with how to handle the (P) and (C) cases, much less the complexities that follow with the year values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty solution is to just use alternation. For example, `(abc|def)` will match `abc` or `def`.

For your case: `^(\(P\)|\(C\)|P|C|©) (19|20)\d{2} .*`

Comment: Thank you - this was an effective suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text, '^([CP©]|\([CP]\)) (19|20)[0-9]{2} .*');
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a great solution that you can try.

Regex-pattern:

```
^([PC©]|\([PC]\))\s((?:19|20)\d{2})\s(.*)$
```

Let's try your first sample:

`(P) 2004 XYZ Company P 2018 This is some random text (C) 1994 More Random Text`

1. Group 1: `(P)`
2. Group 2: `2004`
3. Group 3: `XYZ Company P 2018 This is some random text (C) 1994 More Random Text`

[Example](https://regexr.com/72tob)